# Adding methods to existing class without much changes

Tags: php, oop, include, extends

i need to include new methods into an existing class without changing too much inside that class. I dont know how to do this. Since i cannot use eg `include_once('mynew.class.php')` and then write all my new code inside, i tried the following and it works.

I can add new methods inside B and they are processes by A as i want them to.

```
class A extends B {
"the existing code"
}
class B {
 "my new code"
}
```

I think this is not the right way, because in this case B should have the main logic and A should get the new code, right?

I don't now how to simulate something like `include` inside a class.

Of course i can write my new functions inside existing A without inheritance, but in this case i want to do as i explained, and barely touch the existing files.

Any suggestions? Hope anyone understands this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a trait? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: No. I will have a closer look on that. So this is suited for this kind of problem? Im obviously not that experienced...

Comment: It basically lets you reuse (or include in your case) functions in classes. It should work for you.

Comment: This only seems to extend existing methods...kinda reusing them?
Or do i miss something...I need new method, regardless of the existing. Sorry if i get this wrong.

Comment: Check my code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). It basically lets you reuse (or include in your case) functions in a class.

**Code example**

```
<?php
trait SayHello {
   public function sayHello() {
       echo 'Hello';
   }
}

class Base {
    use SayHello;
}

$o = new Base();
$o->sayHello();
?>
```

Comment: Nice, glad it helped.

Comment: Just one more question...This solutions works like charm but is my first approach generally WRONG or CAN you do this, without upsetting another programmer?

Comment: For your problem of inserting more functions into a class, it should work too but a better way is for class `B` having the new codes to inherit class `A` then you use the object of class `B` where you need to access the properties of `A` and/or `B` since `B` _is a_ `A`